# imaplib.error: SELECT command error: BAD [b'User is authenticated but not connected.']

Tags: python, python-3.x, pop3, imaplib

### My Requirement

I am trying to access the **unread emails** from outlook mail using **Python.** Upon my initial research I have found that using **POP3** we cannot able to classify **read mails and unread mails.**  I came to know that **IMAP** is the best fit for my use case.

### What have I tried so far

```
import imaplib
imap_server = "imap-mail.outlook.com"
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server, 993)
status, message = imap.login(my_mail, my_pass)
print(f'Status: {status}\nMessage: {message[0].decode()}')
status, message = imap.select(mailbox='INBOX')
print(status, message)
imap.close()
imap.shutdown()
```

I am using outlook mail id and server i used to connect is **imap-mail.outlook.com** with **port 993**. 
When I am trying to **imap.login()** as in the above code, I am receiving **Status: OK, Message: LOGIN completed.** 
But when I am trying to select the mailbox using **imap.select()** as in the above code, I am getting error as 
**imaplib.error: SELECT command error: BAD [b'User is authenticated but not connected.']**

My mailid and password are correct and i can able to login in browser. And also tried changing the **imap_server** to **outlook.office365.com** but no luck.

##### Full Traceback for your understanding

```
Status: OK
Message: LOGIN completed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/AutoEmail/auto_email.py", line 10, in <module>
  status, message = imap.select(mailbox='INBOX')
  File "C:\Users\Pavan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", 
                                                           line 745, in select
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
  File "C:\Users\Pavan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", 
                                                           line 1196, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Users\Pavan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", 
                                                           line 1027, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SELECT command error: BAD [b'User is authenticated but not connected.']
```

Can anyone guide me in the correct path or suggest any other alternative approach to do this.

**already has the POP and IMAP enabled in settings**
[image]

Comment: Apparently, this means your username was valid, but your password was not.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164823/user-is-authenticated-but-not-connected-after-changing-my-exchange-password

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts Thanks for your reply.. but my password is valid and I can able to login successfully in the browser.

Comment: Are you sure your account is configured for IMAP access?  IMAP access and POP3 access are separate permissions in Exchange.  Have you tried using an IMAP client, like Thunderbird, to access your account?

Comment: My account is configured for IMAP access.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for you suggestion. Even though in browser it is displaying IMAP enabled but I cannot set it up in Thunderbird. So from my observation your observation is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Happens here randomly. Mailbox check runs periodically every 5mins, works fine for most of the time, then randomly there's a peak of half an hour of failures.